# Scrollbar in div scroll instead of page scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I was building my site I can came across a little problem.
I have a div with a fixed height and overflow:auto;. The height of the website will adjust itself to fit the page perfectly so that you dont get a scrollbar. My question is: Can I pass through the scroll event that happends in the page and redirect it to the scrollbar ? So in other words, when I scroll, not the page, but the scrollbar inside my div has to move.

I hope I made myself clear, if not, please ask for some more information.

With kindly regards,
Bob

FIXED: The solution Andy brought up worked like a charm! Thank you and thanks all of you for your suggestions ^^.

Comment: You should really up vote the answer that worked for you and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, I have used it in the past:

```
div {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a possible solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTXqQ/

I'm using the **[Mousewheel](http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/demos) Plugin**

Comment: I don't think the mousewheel plugin is necessary. The scrolling effect will still work as expected without it.

Comment: Strange. If you go to your jsfiddle, delete the javascript and the link to the mousewheel plugin you will see that the box still scrolls up and down even with the wheel on your mouse.

Comment: @tw16: Even if you click outside the box then scroll?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way to do this is by fixing the content of everything else on the page and positioning your `div` such that it is in the "window" framed by the fixed content. If you can post your HTML, we may be able to help more.

Comment: I think you can do it with `overflow:scroll;`

Comment: This depends on the layout of the HTML. The fact that what the OP is doing is not already produces the intended result suggests that an alternative technique is necessary.