# How to give scrollbar to the div in mobile

Tags: php, css, facebook, html

Can anyone please tell me how to give a scrollbar to the div? In my program, I am listing my Facebook friends inside a div. I have given fixed height to the div. I will paste the code.

```
<div id="main_fb">
   <div id="friend_list">

   // friendlist code.......

 </div>
</div>
```

And the css is :

```
 #main_fb {

        height:250px;
 }


 #friend_list {

        overflow-y:scroll;
        height:224px;
        width:100%;
        overflow:none;

 }
```

Is there any wrong in my code? Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have `overflow-y: scroll` and then `overflow:none`, I think they are conflicting somehow.
For webkit on touch devices there is the vendor specific `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` but it is only supported on recent versions.
For more info see here: [How much support is there for -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768363/how-much-support-is-there-for-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch)

Comment: OK for most mobile browsers (at least in Android and iOS you my want to use, in addition to `overflow-y: scroll;`, the vendor-specific `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` give it a go and let us know. In case it does not work try to provide more data, maybe a jsfiddle.

Comment: Also as I was saying in the edited answer see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768363/how-much-support-is-there-for-webkit-overflow-scrollingtouch

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a chance that the second `overflow` is overriding the first `overflow-y` in your CSS. Because you already specified width as 100% of the page, I would personally simplify things by just using `overflow:scroll;` and forget about the `overflow-y` property.

Related SOF question: [Scrollbar in div scroll instead of page scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653668/scrollbar-in-div-scroll-instead-of-page-scrollbar)

Comment: I just noticed that you are using this in mobile. As in on a mobile browser or on a PhoneGap/Cordova app?

Comment: Also, you are not going to have a scrollbar appear because your container div (main_fb) has a larger height than your containing div (friend_list).

Comment: I am running this program on a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue bro. refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16859957/2163837) if you are stuck with similar situation. In my case I ultimately learned that, scrolling is ignored in android 2.3.x versions I don't know what's your target device, but still might be helpful, I guess.